# Scrapping links and PDFs using Python or R

Tags: python, r, web-scraping

so i have a doubt about how to make these tasks using web scrapping in Python or in R. Prefer in Python. The tasks are following down:

- I need to list the PDF files available in a website and list the URL too.
- Find the broken links in the website.
  I have been trying using these code that i find in google, but it don't return the broken links list.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def get_broken_links(url):

    # Set root domain.
    root_domain = domain.com
    
    # Internal function for validating HTTP status code.
    def _validate_url(url):
        r = requests.head(url)
        if r.status_code == 404:
            broken_links.append(url)
            
    # Make request to URL.      
    data = requests.get(url).text
    
    # Parse HTML from request.
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, features="html.parser")
    
    # Create a list containing all links with the root domain.
    links = [link.get("href") for link in soup.find_all("a") if f"//{root_domain}" in link.get("href")]
    
    # Initialize list for broken links.
    broken_links = []
    
    # Loop through links checking for 404 responses, and append to list.
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as executor:
        executor.map(_validate_url, links)
        
    return broken_links
```

Comment: Perhaps provide the link to the site so we can help you?